# How to calculate the cosine similarity between two words (word2vec in matlab)?

Tags: matlab, word2vec

I have this parameters form word2vec_matlab, and I want to calculate the cosine similarity distance

```
wordvecs_norm - Normalized word vectors
word2Index    - Map of words to indeces
input         - Input word (string)
k             - Number of words to return
```

I tried

```
 word1 = ('king');
 word2 = ('queen');
 cosine = dot(wordvecs(word1)/ wordvecs_norm(word1), wordvecs(word2)/ wordvecs_norm(word2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia gives this as formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity
[image]

I think this translates in MATLAB to:

`wv1 = wordvecs(word1)
wv2 = wordvecs(word2)
cosine = dot(wv1,wv2)/ (sqrt(dot(wv1,wv1))*sqrt(dot(wv2,wv2)))`

Let me know if it works!